# JOLT concatenate two strings

Tags: json, jolt

I have this collection of driver details and I want to use jolt to copy the properties to concatenate first name and last name within a single property called **name**

```
{
  "drivers_details": [
    {
      "first_name": "Doru",
      "last_name": "Petre",
      "cnp": "1641201390687",
      "id_series": "RK",
      "id_number": "123456"
    },
    {
      "first_name": "GIGI",
      "last_name": "FANE",
      "cnp": "16412013906871",
      "id_series": "RK",
      "id_number": "1234567"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am using this spec for the **shift** transformation spec

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "drivers_details": {
        "*": {
          "cnp": "body.drivers[&1].tin",
          "id_series": "body.drivers[&1].id_series",
          "id_number": "body.drivers[&1].id_number"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

and this one for modify-overwrite, but it doesn't work how I was expecting

```
 {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "drivers_details": {
        "*": {
           "name": "=concat(@(2,first_name),' ',@(2,last_name))"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "body": {
        "drivers_details": {
          "*": {
            "name": "=concat(@(1,first_name),' ',@(1,last_name))"
          }
        }
  }}} the entire modify spec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **modify** transformation as in the following case, and get rid of ***name***s other than newly formed attribute ***name*** such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "drivers_details": {
        "*": {
          "name": "=concat(@(1,first_name),' ',@(1,last_name))"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "drivers_details": {
        "*": {
          "*name": ""
        }
      }
    }
  }, 
  { // this last spec stands only for ordering of the attributes if the ordering and putting the "name" at the top matters.
    // So, you might get rid of the "remove" transformation above if this is used. Otherwise keep it.
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "drivers_details": {
        "*": {
          "name": "&2[&1].&",
          "cnp": "&2[&1].&",
          "id*": "&2[&1].&"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

where those attributes(first/last_name) stays right-hand-side at the current  level, so just only need to traverse **1** colon(`:`) which appears as `@(1,..)`

Comment: i end up with `"drivers" : [ {
      "tin" : "1641201390687",
      "id_series" : "RK",
      "id_number" : "123456"
    }, {
      "tin" : "16412013906871",
      "id_series" : "RK",
      "id_number" : "1234567"
    } ]`

Comment: Can you edit the input and spec within the question again, seems there is some issue for the current one, so I've tried to fix them @caputz (lately I've noticed the details of the comment which is more correct than the one presented within the question)

Comment: i've edited but there are not a lot of changes

Comment: As far as I observe, you didn't touch the input(still as I've edited). Thus, my solution should handle the issue, doesn't it? @caputz

Comment: i figured out the problem. the problem was that in the modify overwrite i wasnt targeting the right name for the collection. it shouldve been drivers not driver_details

Comment: @caputz yes, you're targeting not the current, but the upper level by traversing an extra `{` character as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this spec without the `remove` operation:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "name": "=concat(@(1,first_&),' ',@(1,last_&))"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "name": "&2[&1].&",
          "cnp": "&2[&1].&",
          "id_*": "&2[&1].&"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```